# impossible to execute the project while a host application is not defined, delphi rad studio

Tags: delphi, parameters, exe, rad-studio, bpl

I'am a newbie at delphi, and when i try to run my project on RAD STUDIO 10.3 IDE, I get the following error (impossible to execute the project while a host application is not defined): [image]

Cannot run project unless a host application is defined. Use the Run|Parameters .. dialog box.

I do not understand what needs to be entered in the Run forms.

Help.

I tried to change the package output by defining a .exe in the parameters but it only launch this .exe.

Comment: A Delphi package is nothing more than a standard DLL with some specifications. So just as a DLL cannot be run on its own and has to be loaded by another application, so does a Delphi package.

Comment: Yes, you probably started your project by mistakenly choosing "File > New > Package", instead of one of the more typical "File > New > Windows VCL Application", "File > New > Multi-Device Application" or "File > New > Console Application". A Package is a special partial application that requires more surrounding parts to it.

Comment: Or you're executin a DLL project. What type of project are you executing?

Comment: I'm not about creating a new project, but I have received a project from a client, and then I opened the project (using the .dproj file) in RAD STUDIO IDE, after that I execute then the problem... otherwise when I create my own projects it works fine. Any help please ?

Comment: @RidaElmaaroufi you were clearly given a project for a Package, not an application. To run it, you need a Host application that uses the Package at runtime. If the client didn't give you one, you will need to make your own. Unless the project is for an IDE Package, in which case you can use the IDE application as the Host

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you tell me please how can I make my own Host, or how can I use the IDE application as the Host ? thank you in advance !

Comment: @RidaElmaaroufi that is entirely dependent on how the project is setup in the first place, and is outside the scope of this post's question. The answer to this post is "your project is dependent on outside code to run it". You need to talk to your client and find out why they didn't give you everything you need to run the project in the first place.